# Create an array from data in a table using Python

Tags: python, arrays

I want to get data from a table in a text file into a python array. The text file that I am using as an input has 7 columns and 31 rows. Here is an example of the first two rows:

```
10672   34.332875   5.360831    0.00004035881220    0.00000515052523    4.52E-07    6.5E-07

12709   40.837833   19.429158   0.00012010938453    -0.00000506426720   7.76E-06    2.9E-07
```

The code that I have tried to write isn't working as it is not reading one line at a time when it goes through the for loop.

```
data = []
f = open('hyadeserr.txt', 'r')
while True:
    eof = "no"
    array = []
for i in range(7):
    line = f.readline()
    word = line.split()
    if len(word) == 0:
        eof = "yes"
    else:
        array.append(float(word[0]))
        print array
if eof == "yes": break
data.append(array)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to parse the file. And why exactly do you use `"yes"` and `"no"` strings instead of `True` and `False`?!

Comment: The way your code is indented, you'd never escape the first `while` loop.

Answer (score 6):

A file with space-separated values is just a dialect of the classic [comma-separated values (CSV)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file where the delimiter is a space (), followed by more spaces, which can be ignored.

Happily, Python comes with a [**`csv.reader`**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) `class` that understands [dialect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect)s.

You should use this:

### Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv

csv.register_dialect('ssv', delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)

data = []
with open('hyadeserr.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, 'ssv')
    for row in reader:
        floats = [float(column) for column in row]
        data.append(floats)

print data
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use cvs here, since you don't really need it:

```
data = []
with open("hyadeserr.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        data.append([float(f) for f in line.strip().split()])
```

Or, if you know for sure that the only extra chars are spaces and line ending `\n`, you can turn the last line into:

```
data.append([float(f) for f in line[:-1].split()])
```

Comment: N.B: [**`file`**](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=file#file) is a Python built-in and therefore a bad choice for an identifier. I'd still recommend using the CSV (not "cvs") module from the standard library to avoid reinventing the wheel with respect to stripping, splitting, line-endings, error-handling, *et cetera*.